# como añadir nuevo dato en firebase desde android?

Tags: android, firebase, studio

Quisiera saber como o que hago mal al intentar hacer un nuevo dato en el nodo de negocios. Lo que pasa es que estoy trabajando con links de imágenes y las agregaría a al nodo de negocio cuando sea subida, de una en una, pero al hacerlo solo cambia el nombre del child img1 y su valor, y lo que quiero hacer es que se agregue otro campo con su respectivo url de la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui mi codigo

```
if(img.equals("icono")){
        mapicono.put("icono", url);
        mDatabase.child("Negocio").child(id).setValue(mapicono).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(Negocios.this, "Se ha guardado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mapicono.clear();
    }
    if (img.equals("img1")){
        mapimg1.put("img1", url);
        mDatabase.child("Negocio").child(id).setValue(mapimg1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(Negocios.this, "Se ha guardado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mapimg1.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara, sobre todo aquí: *pero al hacerlo solo cambia el nombre del child img1 y su valor, y lo que quiero hacer es que se agregue otro campo con su respectivo url de la imagen*  ... Si quieres un nuevo par clave-valor, puedes crear un `Map` y luego agregarlo al nodo mediante `updateChildren()` ([ver más  detalles aquí](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?hl=es#update_specific_fields))

Comment: si funciono amigo, publicalo como respuesta porfa, gracias!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
mapimg1.put("img1", url);
```

Esta línea sobreescribe el valor del `child("img1")`. Para añadir un nuevo campo **creo** que debes añadir un nuevo `child`:

```java
mapimg1.put("urlImagen", url);

mDatabase.child("Negocio").child(id)**.child("urlImagen")**.setValue(mapimg1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {

   @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
        Toast.makeText(Negocios.this, "Se ha guardado la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
mapi

mg1.clear();
```

Así podrás poner cada vez la dirección de la imagen.